# How can I run teardown code when the Flash VM closes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Is there a way to register code to be run when Flash is about to close (e.g., when the user closes the browser or when DOM manipulation causes the embedded player to be removed)?

In particular, I'd like for my application to send a closing packet to a remote service so the user's peers know that the user has no chance of coming back without having to wait for a timeout. I'm using URLLoader and URLRequest to maintain a BOSH connection, so I welcome solutions applicable to this specific case. However, if there are NetConnection-specific solutions, I'm sure I can learn from them too.

I'm happy to accept that this callback won't be run on a `kill -9` but it would be nice to have the more graceful exit paths allow for some code execution.

Comment: How about overriding the js's window.close to send your event?  Problem there is then allowing the user to close / send them on their way.

Comment: @DanielH, we've considered the option of doing it at the JS level like with window.onBeforeUnload. The session is established maintained (and thus would be most easily closed) within Flash, so the most reliable way of disconnect would be inside the VM. We've found that listening at the JS level and using ExternalInterface to trigger Flash code is very unreliable.

Comment: I don't know very much about BOSH aside from it using keep-alives --  it seems strange to me that the server wouldn't be able to detect disconnection.  Will write up something about RTMP below.

Comment: @StevenXu, unfortunately, window.onBeforeUnload and ExternalInterface are the only solution. Flash Player is unloaded by the browser, so the unreliable window.onBeforeUnload is the only way to detect that this is happening. Whatever code you do trigger should try to not try to do too much work, to increase the chance of success. (I don't know anything about BOSH either :)

Comment: FYI, [this is the specific problem](http://blog.vokle.com/index.php/2009/03/10/why-ie-doesnt-drop-flash-netconnections-netstreams-and-how-to-fix-it/) I (and the guys at Vokel) had and solved with window.onBeforeUnload and ExternalInterface.

Comment: @DanielH Most Flash applications are like HTML/AJAX applications.  They do not have a permanent connection to a server. So, the server disconnection happens at the end of every request.  Now, if you have a server side session, I suspect most server technologies allow you to run code when the session expires.  ( I know that CF and .NET can ).  But, none of that will have an effect on the client session.

Comment: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html  BOSH is a keep-alive http connection.

Comment: Hmm, it's a painful idea, but anyway... You can open a background pop-up with Flash app _monitoring_ state of your main app through LocalConnection. Maybe it's possible to close session opened by main app with _monitor_ app in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the better solution would be to do this via the server side no?  The server should be able to detect the disconnection, where you could then invalidate the session.

However, you could go with a client/socket based solution, albeit much more overhead.  Using FMS or some other rtm real time server you could dispatch events to your web server that a connection has dropped, (though you might have issues in the case of low network connectivity, or an internet drop).  I would suggest going against this though, as in my experience, FMS sucks :)

Is setting extremely low timeouts not a possibility? (i.e. < 10 seconds)

Comment: I'd like to have modestly long timeouts before reaping the session to allow for temporary network disruptions (e.g., brief loss of a Wi-Fi connection) to be recovered from gracefully. As a result, having a timeout of at least 30 seconds would be nice. In any case, the server can relatively quickly determine if a client has lost connectivity. The key thing I'm trying to differentiate between is lost connection due to a temporary network issue (in which case we should give the client time to reconnect) or a lost connection due to the Flash VM closing (in which case others should be notified).

Comment: Yeah, I think you're SOL here, without writing your own browser extension.